# Publicly available poker stats

Tags: texas-hold-em, statistics

Are there any sources of poker hands, including how they play out with betting etc... I am imagining the log files of some poker site somewhere.

I am looking for complete hand histories - and especially interested in tournament play.

I am only really interested in Texas Holdem No Limit, but any link to something that might lead to some stats would be great.

Comment: I have a small question for you: if you find something that fits this criteria, what will you do with that information ? Are you trying to learn the game that way ? Are you trying to make an AI (Artificial Intellignce) system ?

Comment: @SoboLAN I want to be able to test the quality of robots, as I am thinking of making a poker site that features robots. Also, for my own interest, I want to try a bit of data mining on the results, to see if there are any unknown strategies that could be profitable - for example, betting on low joined suited cards on the off chance that something unexpected and good comes up in the flop, catching the opponent off guard - they never expect a full house of 7s and 2s if you bet pre-flop. I want to find out if that could ever be profitable, or any other unusual patterns.

Answer (score 21):

Not sure if it covers the games you're looking for but it's a useful resource to mention anyway.

[University of Alberta Computer Poker Research Group Database](http://poker.cs.ualberta.ca/irc_poker_database.html) has something like *10 Million* hands for free to download. Check it out.

As a side note, their papers about Poker AI and decision making are always very insightful.

Comment: Well that is the closest I have come so far to what I want. I really want to know the folded cards too, but I guess that might be asking too much. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You're welcome :). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

Caution: Buying hand histories are against rules on most poker sites!

Anyway... The most known shops with handhistories are :

http://www.hhsmithy.com/

http://www.pokertableratings.com/buy-hand-histories

I have never tried them, so I can't tell you anything about usefullnes of these services, also I'm not sure if they provide tournaments histories.

Long time ago, I saw some site with anonymized hand histories for science/math research but despite my effort, I can't find that site now.

Gl at tables!

Comment: It seems hand histories were made available by bodog, but I think only for your own games. Still, I would expect someone has archived a decent amount of games they played, and made it available. I can't find any though...

Comment: Plenty of individual players have hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of hands in their databases (I have somewhere around 400k and my volume was never that great). Problem is, they won't give it away without a huge price because of all of the valuable information it has.

Answer (score 4):

Here you will find http://web.archive.org/web/20110205042259/http://www.outflopped.com/questions/286/obfuscated-datamined-hand-histories

70 GB of hands

Comment: Nice, but doesn't include data on unshown hands.

Answer (score 1):

There is an UCI Dataset for this purpose [UCI Poker Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Poker+Hand)

Comment: OP (and myself) are looking for complete hand histories.  here there is only hands of players.  It misses the actions players toke.

Answer (score 0):

[High Stakes DB](https://www.highstakesdb.com/results.aspx) has records for most if not all online hands that are 25/50+.

Note that the site wasn't working well at the time of this post, and I haven't looked at their DB in over a year.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could check out https://pokerstats.app.
They do not offer hand histories but they do offer advanced statistics like player frequencies, bet sizing and much more!