# Are there any good Poker hand history databases for free out there?

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand-history

I'm doing a project on poker AI's for my senior thesis and I was wondering if anyone knows about any hand history data openly available? By hand history database I mean game logs where everything is saved about the games cards dealt to each player, bet amounts/actions taken by each player, pot size, etc. Specifically, I am interested in Texas Hold'em games with bet limits.
Thanks for your help in advance,

Comment: Possible duplication of ["Publicly Available Poker Stats"](http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/881/88) question. There is a resource for poker hands in my answer [here](http://poker.stackexchange.com/a/900/88)

Comment: Have in mind that not every site allows using history databases for HUD.